# Getting variables values from URL after being dynamically added by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code below

```
var delLink = $('#deleteItem').attr('href');
```

to get the URL `(href)` of a link identified by `#deleteItem`.

The problem occurs when I use JQuery to add new variables onto this URL and I want to see the new dynamically added variables also displayed by the above code.

How can this be done, now it only displays the orginal URL without any of the new variables.

Thanks

Comment: _I want to see the new dynamically added variables?_ Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you give any example how the "variables are added dynamically"?

Comment: `delLink` is not a pointer to the `href` attribute. It just saves a copy of what's in it. You need to update it manually if you want it to be synchronised.

Comment: @w4rumy - How I add my variables `$('#deleteItem').attr('href',delLink+','+allVals);`

Comment: @undefined - I'm using `alert();` to see the URL after using the function above(previous comment) to add the new variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delLink contains the result of your query. It is not a reference to href.

```
// Assigns the value of href to delLink
var delLink = $('#deleteItem').attr('href');

// Changes the href value on the DOM element
$('#deleteItem').attr('href',delLink+','+allVals);
```

delLink does not know about the update, to update delLink you again need to execute:

```
delLink = $('#deleteItem').attr('href');
```

What you could to make it a little easier for you is cache the jQuery object reference to the anchor element in the DOM and simply keep accessing the href attribute from it:

```
// Create a jQuery object reference to the anchor element in the DOM
var $delLink = $('#deleteItem');

// Changes the href value in on DOM element
var currentHref = $delLink.attr('href');
$('#deleteItem').attr('href', currentHref + ',' + allVals); 

// Results are available through your reference
$delLink.attr('href');
```